# Full transparency on Ubuntu 18.04 dock

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

This command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode
```

can have these values: 'FIXED' 'DEFAULT' 'DYNAMIC' 'ADAPTIVE'.

But none makes the dock bar completely transparent, that is, only the icons are visible.

any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command first to allow custom alpha values for Ubuntu dock

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas true
```

Then run the following to set the minimum alpha value (i.e. when a window is *not* maximised or touching the top-bar or dock)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha 0
```

Finally, if you want, run the following to set the maximum alpha value (i.e. when a window is maximised)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 0
```

Then log out and log in again.

Comment: If this doesn't work, use the `dconf-editor` to edit this options via a graphical user interface

Answer (score 3):

this work for me,

- open `dconf-editor`
- goto `/org/gnome/shell/extentions/dash-to-dock/backgound-opacity`
- default value : `off`
- set to `'0'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome extension Ubuntu Dock, you can shut that off and turn on Dash to Dock.  Make your changes in there and then switch them back.  I don't like Dash to Dock because it causes two docks to be displayed when I click on Activities.  I just use it to configure the dock.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting here from google, this works on Ubuntu 20.10

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity 0
```