# How to make Dash-to-Panel in Ubuntu 18.04 transparent on maximized windows?

Tags: themes, dock, gnome-tweak-tool, transparency, ubuntu-dock

I've already tried the following: [Full transparency on Ubuntu 18.04 dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031334/full-transparency-on-ubuntu-18-04-dock)

But I just need to make the panel transparent, and I can't find any way to do so successfully.

The gray opaque panel doesn't look too good in this image:
[image: The gray opaque panel doesn't look too good in this image]

Comment: yes, but after following those steps, I still have an opaque dock

Comment: Hang on, that doesn't even look like Ubuntu dock. Are you using "dash to panel"?

Comment: That's definitely dash to panel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The steps you followed are related to the original Dock in Ubuntu 18.04, but you are *clearly* using [Dash-to-Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) GNOME extension which can be made transparent easily using another GNOME extension called [Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/).

To specify custom transparency values, all you need to do is:

1. Enable the extension from [Dynamic Panel Transparency's page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) on extensions.gnome.org.
2. Refresh [the extension's page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) for the setting icon to appear. (top-right, next to the enable switch)
3. Access the extension's settings and go to `Background` tab.
4. Enable `Enable custom opacity` and set your custom values.
5. Done.

Comment: Also *clearly* is a pun on transparent :) +1 for pun be it intended or not.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix didn't really think about it like that, I wrote it in italic because he might be using a different fork (who knows?), but thanks for the up :)

Comment: @developer067 you're welcome

Comment: Pomsky used "clearly" in his comment under OP''s question too. Puns galore!

Comment: "Access the extension's settings". How?

Comment: @RandyCragun I added an instruction on how to access the settings page.