# After Upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 the right dock background color remains black, can't set to transparency mode

Tags: ubuntu-dock, 18.10

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 with my right dock with transparency. After updating, the background dock color is black. I followed the steps answered here: [Full transparency on Ubuntu 18.04 dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031334/full-transparency-on-ubuntu-18-04-dock)
but the backgorund dock color still remains black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in 18.10 they have introduced "Yaru" some new themeing style.
by default this dock is themed by `#1d1d1d` color under /* Yaru Dock styling */
you need it to make it to `none` or any color you want.

[image]

[image]

to do so, run the below command in terminal.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` # change the gedit if you use any other editor.

go to line number 2212 `background: #1d1d1d;`

```
#dashtodockContainer.shrink.left #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock.left #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.shrink.right #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock.right #dash {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px; }
```

change the line `background: #1d1d1d;` to `background: none;`

so that it looks like

```
#dashtodockContainer.shrink.left #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock.left #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.shrink.right #dash,
#dashtodockContainer.dashtodock.right #dash {
  background: none;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px; }
```

In the same way go to line number 2150 & 2156 and change the value to none

```
#dashtodockContainer.opaque {
  /* Only alpha value is used */
  background-color: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition-duration: 500ms; }


#dashtodockContainer.transparent {
  /* Only alpha value is used */
  background-color: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition-duration: 500ms; }
```

Save the file & Close.

run these 3 commands in terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas true  
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 0.00000000001  
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha 0.00000000001
```

Reboot to see the change.

Still there is a Black Color Border visible,
you can change it by line number 1292 either none or any valid preferred color.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. Changed background to none but the dock still remains in black (or some dark color). I was using Ubuntu 18.04 and gdm3 but after upgrading my system wont show the login screen. So I had to change to lightdm. I dont know if the issue is related to this.