# Ubuntu Dock -- Set a custom transparency level on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I want it to be something like 90% opaque, so the icons are easier to see on light-colored themes.

Comment: what is your Ubuntu Version? have you installed dconf-editor tool?? with the tool you can set..

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 I have dconf-editor and I looked around a little,  but I couldn't find the right place for this tweak for Ubuntu18.10.

Comment: you can invoke with dconf-editor and search for dash-to-dock you will see lot of options

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/q/1086473/739431

Comment: Thanks. That last link looks right, as they changed something in Ubuntu 18.10, and the simple dconf Editor tweak doesn't work anymore.